# Finding Word Length

Tags: python, windows

I am looking for a script that can open myfile.txt, read it and count the number of words that have 10 or more letters in the file. I made several attempts and consistently receive syntax errors. Need help.

Comment: Can you share the code from the most successful of your attempts?  What's the part you get stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
f = open("myfile.txt")
data = f.read()
wc = 0
for x in data.split():
  if len(x) >= 10:
    wc += 1

print(wc)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    word_list = input_file.read().split()
    print(len(list(filter(lambda x: len(x)>10, word_list))))
```

There are a lot of different solutions though. What did you try?

Comment: Invalid syntax error (lamba x: len(x)>10. It was on the x! But thanks.